# Can I do subtotals with a grand total in a MySql query?

Tags: mysql

So I have a query that breaks down counts by 2 columns.  The query goes like this:

```
SELECT `Location`, `Model Name`, Count
FROM (
    SELECT IF(`Location` = @Prev, NULL, `Location`) AS 'Location',
           `Model Name`, 
           Count, 
           @Prev := `Location`
    FROM (SELECT `locations`.`location_name` AS 'Location', 
             `inventory`.`equip_model` AS 'Model Name', 
             count(`inventory`.`equip_model`) AS 'Count' 
          FROM mod_inventory_data AS `inventory` 
          LEFT JOIN mod_locations_rooms AS `rooms` ON `rooms`.room_id = `inventory`.room_id 
          WHERE inventory.equip_model LIKE '%optiplex%'  
          GROUP BY `Location`, `Model Name`) AS subq
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Prev := NULL) AS init
    ) AS subq2
```

The query above will produce output like :

```
location 1   optiplex 745   24
             optiplex 755   18
             optiplex 780   30
location 2   optiplex 745   15
             optiplex 755   22
             optiplex 780   25
```

Is there a way to modify this to give me something like this:

```
location 1   optiplex 745   24
             optiplex 755   18
             optiplex 780   30
                   TOTAL:   72

location 2   optiplex 745   15
             optiplex 755   22
             optiplex 780   25
                   TOTAL:   62

             GRAND TOTAL:  134
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Dan B.

Comment: See the `WITH ROLLUP` modifier: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that. I changed the "GROUP BY `Location`, `Model Name`) AS subq" to "GROUP BY `Location`, `Model Name` WITH ROLLUP) AS subq", and it worked perfectly. Thanks for curing my brain fart.